# Thread dont flush data, cannot get all the data from stdin

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating a socket program to transfer data from one pc to another, but i have a problem when i send some binary data to process to the other side.
In this case i need one thread to listen the message socket while the data socket send the data.
So i discovered that the problem wasn't the socket, the problem happens if i try to just write the data to the screen (no socket this time).
So i tried to flush the data using fflush(stdout) and no luck.
The codes work in this way.

```
Initialize the 2 sockets.
Initialize 2 threads.
  One to get the data back through the data socket.
  The other send the data.    
And while sending all the data one pthread_join(m_thread2) in the main function, because the data can take 1 second to be processed or one hour so i keep the program alive this way.
```

I created a smaller version using two thread to read and send to the screen and in the main just the while.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int RCVBUFSIZE=2000;
char echoString[RCVBUFSIZE];
int recvMsgSize;
static void * _sendExec(void *instance);
static void * _recvExec(void *instance);
int main(){
  pthread_t m_thread, m_thread2;
  int merror, merror2;
  merror=pthread_create(&m_thread, NULL, _sendExec, NULL);
  merror2=pthread_create(&m_thread2, NULL, _recvExec, NULL);
  pthread_join(m_thread2, NULL);
}
static void * _sendExec(void *instance){
  int size;
  for(;;){
    while((size=read(fileno(stdin), echoString, RCVBUFSIZE))>0){
       write(fileno(stdout), echoString, size);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_exit(0);
  }
}
static void * _recvExec(void *instance){
  while(1){
     //recvMsgSize=msgTmp->recv(buffer, RCVBUFSIZE)
     write(fileno(stdout), "", 0);
     sleep(1);
  }
}
```

if you try `cat file.tar.gz | ./a.out | tar -zvt` you can see that not all the data is showed on the screen, if i put on the main, remove the pthread_join its ok, the problem is i need the data back and it can take time.
It's just like if i do an `cat file.tar.gz | ssh root@server "tar -zvt"`.
The problem is, i just can kill the sendExec after receive all the data back using the recvExec, but it just flush the stdin to me after 
Changed the code and removed the socket part, just to illustrate the problem

Thanks people

Comment: It dont happen, because they dont write on the same var.

Comment: They do in this code. Don't post code that isn't the actual code, it'll just be confusing.

Comment: sorry, but one write in the echoString and the another receive in the buffer. Only if im lazzy now XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `tar` is waiting for more input because you never provide an end-of-file indication. Try this:

```
static void * _sendExec(void *instance){
  int size;
  for(;;){
    while((size=read(fileno(stdin), echoString, RCVBUFSIZE))>0){
       write(fileno(stdout), echoString, size);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(stdout); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT FIXES THE SAMPLE PROGRAM
    pthread_exit(0);
  }
}
```

While adding `fclose` fixes your sample program, I wouldn't necessarily recommend it in your main program. Your sample still has an infinite loop in it (in `_recvExec`) and will never terminate.

Comment: the infinite loop in this case is just an example, but i mentioned i use a socket to send data, the write was just to illustrate, is there a way to close the socket or i need to delete his pointer?

Comment: I send trough socket and in the other side i use pipe/fork to send the data to the program.